# What single feature will enable ultra low latencies for 5G communications?

Tags: radio, latency

there has been a recent buzz around 5G and its ultra low latency use cases. Additionally, some people claim that data rates around 10 Gbps are a feasible scenario if mmWaves are to be used.

I was wondering if, RF propagation characteristics and models apart, mmWaves are a true enabler to ultra low latencies. Is there any particular reason for a signal transmitted at a lower frequency band (say, 2100 MHz) to have higher latencies than the same signal being transmitted at 28 GHz?

Comment: Please define what you mean by latency. Your question hinges on this and, as a secondary thought, I doubt that one single feature will lead to anything much these days so please consider revising your title to make it less problematic to answer. Features do not = performance improvements.

Comment: Hi, and welcome here! We're in 2018 – there's decades of cellular network engineering experience by now. So, likelihood of "a single feature" giving you a big advantage is... not that high :) I do still like the question, but would frame it differently.

Comment: (oh, and by the way, I come from an academic background: "some people say" is about as good as "there's a rumor going around in the canteen", and I'd ask you to say who claims that, but the claim is unrelated to your actual question, so let me not bicker about that but answer your core question as good as I can!)

Comment: The lowest latency will be the one where you loose signal when going around a corner or it starts to rain

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any particular reason for a signal transmitted at a lower frequency band (say, 2100 MHz) to have higher latencies than the same signal being transmitted at 28 GHz?

No, not as far as I can see. The processing is the same, and so is the speed of light.

Only thing is that you might have a higher bandwidth available at higher frequencies, making packets containing only little data shorter than on lower frequencies. But on-the-air packet length for short packets definitely isn't the latency driver.

Most of the latency happens in the network, so on layers far above the physical aspects of transmission like frequency. So all the 5G buzzwording around "low-latency networks" happens on the network layer, typically by bringing more smarts closer to the actual baseband unit.

Another aspect is the question of medium access control: If your cellular standard requires a device to first register with the network, then be asked whether it requests a slot, then request that slot, then be granted that slot, then use that slot and then wait for a reaction, that means latency, and not too little of that, if the ressources are shared with many participants. That again is totally unrelated to carrier frequency. Maybe the quasi-optical propagation properties of mmWaves do help with having smaller cells and hence more efficient (less latency) access methods, but that only complicates the problem: If you have an access point per room because 28 GHz doesn't penetrate walls, then how can the latency be lower if you need data to go from that access point to a centralized station, again through shared media? If the solution is to not share the medium but distribute an optical fibre to every room, than the advantage isn't brought to you by higher frequency, but by a vast explosion of backbone network cost and complexity and energy consumption.

There *is* a measurable contribution to latency caused by things like OFDM necessitating full OFDM symbols, but that doesn't go away on higher frequencies; again, these symbols might become shorter in time, but even that is questionable.

Another issue is that channel codes need to be *long* to be *good*. There's a bit of motion in the field of short-but-tolerable codes, but that's totally unrelated to carrier frequency.

Comment: +1 interestting answer dude.